# VSTO addin slow startup

Tags: excel, performance, profiling, vsto

My VSTO Excel addin is starting up every slowly on one of my client's site (~2 minutes).

I've run `vsperf` on both the client's and my local dev installation.

Comparing the two reports, I noticed that the client's installation is spending a lot of time in `NtUserPeekMessage` (even more than `MSO.dll`), whereas `NtUserPeekMessage` barely registers on mine.

Time spent in my VSTO addin is relatively low, and doesn't appear to be the bottleneck.

The calling functions:

```
NtUserPeekMessage
whNtUserPeekMessage
Wow64SystemServiceEx    
ServiceNoTurbo
RunCpuSimulation
Wow64LdfpInitialize
LdrpInitializeProcess
`string'
LdrInitializeThunk
```

Has anyone faced this issue as well? What else can I look for or try to isolate the slow start up?

[edit]

Client claims the slow start up started a month or so ago. Prior to that, the add in was starting up fine. The problem appears to affect all machines in their network.

Things I have gotten them to test so far: repair office, vsto, reinstall, disable all other addins, installing on a new machine.